# sum rows in two dataframes according to equation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have 2 matrix df:
distance df:

```
   1   2  
1  20 50 
2   5 10
```

time df:

```
  1  2  
1  3 8
2  5 1
```

I want to get  df that sum values for each row  according to the equation: e^ (-b1*i-b2*j)
for each row in the df (both df have the same number of rows), while b1 and b2 is parameters that I later be optimize.
**for example**, I want the result:

```
id     result
1   e^ (-b1*20 -b2*3) + e^ (-b1*50-b2* 8)
2   e^ (-b1*5-b2*5) + e ^ (-b1*10-b2*1)
```

I have try this code:

```
beta1=beta2=2
result=[]
for i in range(dist_df.shape[0]):
    result.append(beta2*beta1*(np.sum([np.exp(-beta1*time_df.iloc[0,i]-beta2*dist_df.iloc[0,i])]))) # for herd 255
    i=i+1
print(result)    
total=sum(result)
print("SUM: " , total)
```

but I need to do it manually for each id

Answer (score 0):

First, you can create a dataframe for the power number:

```
df = -b1 * df1 -b2 * df2
```

Then you can use *apply* to have your final result:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: sum(math.exp(i) for i in x))
```

Comment: The problem is that I do not want to initialize values to b1,b2 ​​but leave them as parameters (later I will be optimized them using MLE)

Comment: @nay I don't think it is possible to calculate this formula with only 2 parameters and not values. I think you should start with two initial values for b1 and b2 and try to optimize them iteratively.